# Ways to dynamically change SQL database through JafaFx table Cell editing

Tags: java, sql, javafx

My javaFx application has many tables with editable table cells to populate data from sql database.I also want to make changes in database after data editing through table cells.According to this toturial "https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm"
I have created my editable table cell with the following code.

```
item_price_col.setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory("price")
); 

item_price_col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
item_price_col.setOnEditCommit(
    new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Item, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<Item,String> t) {

            String old_price=t.getOldValue();

            ((Item) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                ).setPrice(t.getNewValue());
            String new_price=t.getNewValue();

            System.out.println("Old Price:"+old_price);
            System.out.println("New Price:"+new_price);
        }
    }
);
```

But it doesn't make any changes in database after editing.So,I think have to write update Query inside of that handle method.But I can only know old value and new value. I can't make query statement like that "update item set price=new_price where price=old_price".If I update a single price of a item to new value,every items in my item table that have the same price with my edited item will make changes to new price value.Are there any ways to solve this problem?
Here is my item table structure.

```
 item  | CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `whole_sale_price` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `orginal_price` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: Does your `Item` class have a unique id field (i.e. a field that represents the primary key in the database)?

Comment: BTW: use [`CellEditEvent.getRowValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.CellEditEvent.html#getRowValue--) to get the `Item` with a single method call.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.Can you give me more detail or online toturials about how to get the value of a unique column(ID) of edited row by using CellEditEvent.getRowValue().

Answer (score 2):

Keep an `id` field to your item as it is given in the database. 
If you have not primary or unique key in the database probably you made some architectural mistake. Anyway there is a row id specified in some database servers.

```
private int id;  // id field for item object.
```

While updating include id as condition.

```sql
update sometable set price = item.getPrice() where id = item.getId();
```

**I know sql is not well written but I hope you'll get it**

And you don't have to show value of id field in your table grid.

This technique is used in most systems

EDITED 2015.12.18

You have code column in the table. Retrieve by jdbc into your item object's id field.

There is an example

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-update-records.htm

Comment: Thanks for your attention.My item table already have primary key.But the problem is that I don't know how to get that Primary key of my selected  row.In that toturial 'http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJAGDAHE' ,it shows how to get only old value and new value of an edited column.

Comment: You should use jdbc connection and learn its documentation. If you want to search it on google I reccommend you to search like this: "jdbc java2s" or "jdbc tutorialspoint"

Comment: Thanks for your attention.I am now currently using jdbc connection and my javaFx table holds data from my sql database using jdbc.I have created insert and delete quaries for my project.But In that case,I don't know how to get that Primary key of my selected row.It is necessary for me to write query like that "update item set price= new_price_value where id=X".X is a variable that have the unique pirmary key value of my edited row.

Comment: Please edit question by adding database table structure then there will be one-shot-answer

Comment: item  | CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `whole_sale_price` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `orginal_price` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

Comment: You are using code column either primary and unique. Declaring primary makes it unique also...

Comment: Thanks for your attention.I know how to use jdbc driver.I have used insert,delete quaries in my project.My problem is related with javaFx table view.That is  I don't know how to get column value's of edited row inside that setOnEditCommit() function.

Comment: I have to make query inside SetOnEditCommit() function like that "update item set price = new_edited_price where code= code_column_value_of_a_edited_row;"

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2277664?tstart=0             I hope this helps. May be there is a misunderstanding but your question was about how to update one single row in database